# To make application continue to run when power button is pressed

Tags: java, android

Hi i have a push to talk application. My application does not continue to run when i press the power button and lock the screen. I am using wake lock with the flag  PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. How can i provide my application to get voice messages when the user presses the power button.

Comment: onPouse is invoked then. Maybe you could play some voice there.

Comment: Have you given WAKE_LOCK permission?

Comment: Yes i have given the permission.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the event of keypress of Power button

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) 
    {
      // Write your logic
      return true;
    }
  return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Hope this will help you..